# Replace months in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

in `this.sources` I have this kind of array data:

```
this.sources = [
  {
    cost: 50000.5,
    ids: { 1: "11112", 2: "1112", 3: "121212" },
    months: { 1: "54548.5000", 2: "45.0000", 3: "510.5000" },
    name: "test1"
  },
  {
    cost: 12469134.5,
    ids: { 1: "19689", 2: "19690", 3: "19691" },
    months: { 1: "12345678.5000", 2: "0.0000", 3: "50.5000" },
    name: "test2"
  }
];
```

What I need is to replace all data in months for all cases (just to change the 4 decimals to 2) and then return the array with the same structure as it is.

What I tried:

```
this.sources = this.fixDecimal(this.sources);

fixDecimal(source) {
  for ( let elx in source ) {
    let newsource = source[elx];

      for ( let x = 0; x <= 11; x++ ) {
        let result = newsource.months[x];

        if (result) { if (result) { result.map(y => y.toFixed(2));}
  }
  }
  return result;
}
```

However this is not working at all. Is there any simple solution just to fix the decimals in months and return the same array with changed data?

Comment: Can you post a valid input structure, in Javascript syntax?

Comment: I have only this data from DB this.http.get(''xxxxx)
    .then(data=>{
     let result = this.helper.isJson(data.response);
     this.sources = this.fixDecimal(result.sources) || [];

Comment: @wotan - No, you have access to the data, which means you can provide us with a valid example of it in JavaScript syntax. Worst case, run your code and output it to the console via `console.log(JSON.stringify(theData, null, 4));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your solution doesnt work is because you have your values as string and you can't use `toFixed` on a string. The parseFloat in the snippet below mitigates that:

```
for(let i=0; i<dataset.length;i++){
    let months = {};
    // Instead of looping through a hardcoded amount, loop though all the keys:
    Object.keys(dataset[i].months).forEach(function(key) {
        months[key] = parseFloat(dataset[i].months[key]).toFixed(2);
    });
    dataset[i].months = months;
}
```

*This is assuming that you get your results in a variable `dataset`, you might want to tweak this a bit.*

Comment: this is exactly what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your values are strings, and have 4 positions after the decimal separator, you can just [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) off the last two characters:

```js
const months = {
  1: "54548.5000",
  2: "45.0000",
  3: "510.5000"
  // ...
};

for (let m in months) {
  months[m] = months[m].slice(0, -2);
}

console.log(months);
```

Comment: While this is a simple solution and might be 100% what you're looking for, it might be worth a note that after this, they're still strings, not numbers. If you only display the values, this isn't a problem. If you want to to math with it, this might not be ideal.

Comment: yeah, it will be calculated later, but thanks for the advice, didn't realize I worked with string

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want, without modifying the original array. Slice will remove the last 2 characters of each month (you can even use substring here: `v.substring(0, v.length - 2)`) 
:

```js
sources = [
  {
    cost: 50000.5,
    ids: { 1: "11112", 2: "1112", 3: "121212" },
    months: { 1: "54548.5000", 2: "45.0000", 3: "510.5000" },
    name: "test1"
  },
  {
    cost: 12469134.5,
    ids: { 1: "19689", 2: "19690", 3: "19691" },
    months: { 1: "12345678.5000", 2: "0.0000", 3: "50.5000" },
    name: "test2"
  }
];

console.log(sources.map(o => ({...o, months: Object.entries(o.months).reduce((a, [k,v]) => ({...a, [k]: v.slice(0, -2)}), {})})))
```

Or, you could modify the original array:

```js
sources = [
  {
    cost: 50000.5,
    ids: { 1: "11112", 2: "1112", 3: "121212" },
    months: { 1: "54548.5000", 2: "45.0000", 3: "510.5000" },
    name: "test1"
  },
  {
    cost: 12469134.5,
    ids: { 1: "19689", 2: "19690", 3: "19691" },
    months: { 1: "12345678.5000", 2: "0.0000", 3: "50.5000" },
    name: "test2"
  }
];

sources.forEach((o, i) => sources[i].months = Object.entries(o.months).reduce((a, [k,v]) => ({...a, [k]: v.slice(0, -2)}), {}))

console.log(sources)
```